# How to define a view of a layout of a java class that extends Fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragment, layout-inflater

I have a `mainactivity` in its layout `mainactivitylayout.xml` there is a `fragment` and two `buttons`.And I have two java classes extend `fragment`. Each one of these classes has its own layout and each layout has `textview` and one of these layout will inflate the `fragment` view based on pressed `button`.

Now, in the first java class that extends `fragment` i want to define the `textview` which is belongs to its layout.

I read a tutorial and knew that I should define such views in `onActivityCreated()` but to define the `textview` as in the following way `tv = findViewById(R.id.tvID)` does not work because that layout will be inflated through `onCreateView()` first. Now, how to define this view `textview`?

Java:

```
TextView tv;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment00, null);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            /*this will not work, how to define it correctly?
    tv = findViewById(R.id.fragment00Tv00);*/
}

public void setFragmentText(String str){
    tv.setText(str);
}
```

***Update***

I tried to initialize the `textview` inside `onCreateView` but the app. then crashes. and `logcat` generates the below errors:

Logcat_output:

```
05-26 23:35:59.505: E/AndroidRuntime(27737): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-26 23:35:59.505: E/AndroidRuntime(27737): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fragments01/com.example.fragments01.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class fragment
05-26 23:35:59.505: E/AndroidRuntime(27737):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
05-26 23:35:59.505: E/AndroidRuntime(27737):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
05-26 23:35:59.505: E/AndroidRuntime(27737):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:168)
05-26 23:35:59.505: E/AndroidRuntime(27737):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
05-26 23:35:59.505: E/AndroidRuntime(27737):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-26 23:35:59.505: E/AndroidRuntime(27737):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-26 23:35:59.505: E/AndroidRuntime(27737):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
05-26 23:35:59.505: E/AndroidRuntime(27737):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-26 23:35:59.505: E/AndroidRuntime(27737):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-26 23:35:59.505: E/AndroidRuntime(27737):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
05-26 23:35:59.505: E/AndroidRuntime(27737):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
05-26 23:35:59.505: E/AndroidRuntime(27737):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-26 23:35:59.505: E/AndroidRuntime(27737): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class fragment
05-26 23:35:59.505: E/AndroidRuntime(27737):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
05-26 23:35:59.505: E/AndroidRuntime(27737):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
05-26 23:35:59.505: E/AndroidRuntime(27737):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
05-26 23:35:59.505: E/AndroidRuntime(27737):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
05-26 23:35:59.505: E/AndroidRuntime(27737):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
05-26 23:35:59.505: E/AndroidRuntime(27737):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
05-26 23:35:59.505: E/AndroidRuntime(27737):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
```

Comment: inflate error does not seem to be caused by getting textView inside of onCreateView method. It should give same error if you don't try to get textView. Share your layout problem seems to be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your `tv` on `onCreateView` method

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View yourContentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment00, null);
    tv = (TextView) yourContentView.findViewById(R.id.fragment00Tv00);
    return yourContentView;
}
```

Or you can get any view from fragment's content view (get its content view by calling `getView` method):

```
public void setFragmentText(String str){
    TextView tv = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.fragment00Tv00);
    tv.setText(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the following:

In your mainactivity class:

```
public class MainActivity
    extends FragmentActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate( … )
{
    super.onCreate( … );
    setContentView(
    R.layout.main_activity_my);
}
...
}
```

And the layout:
main_activity_my.xml only have to contain the fragment:

```
<fragment />
```

You need another class and another layout that contains your TextView:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment
{
@Override
public View onCreateView( … )
{
    return inflater.inflate(
    R.layout.fragment_layout,
    container,
    false);
}
...
}
```

And the layout fragment_layout that contains the textView:

```
<TextView />
```